# SQL statement for Group Count and Overall Count

Tags: sql, oracle

Given is the following test data:

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ STUDENT ║ TEST ║ SCORE ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ Henry   ║    1 ║    80 ║
║ Henry   ║    2 ║    70 ║
║ Henry   ║    3 ║    50 ║
║ Mark    ║    1 ║    60 ║
║ Mark    ║    2 ║    90 ║
║ Mark    ║    3 ║    70 ║
║ Frank   ║    1 ║    80 ║
║ Frank   ║    2 ║    70 ║
║ Frank   ║    3 ║    80 ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Now I'm interested to see per student who's got how many times a score of 80 and next to it the total count of 80. Something like this:

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ STUDENT ║ OWN_80_CNT ║ TOTAL_80_CNT ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ Frank   ║          2 ║            3 ║
║ Mark    ║          0 ║            3 ║
║ Henry   ║          1 ║            3 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

What I have so far is the own_80_cnt. But i don't know how to add the total_80_cnt just next to it.

```
SELECT  student,
        SUM(CASE WHEN score = 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS own_80_cnt
FROM    mytable 
GROUP BY student;
```

Is this even possible within just one SELECT statement (preferred)? 
DBMS is Oracle.

Comment: In you sample you are showing total count but not the total 80 count :D

Comment: Does not make much sense: Frank own=2 but total is 3? Check out ROLLUP Extension to GROUP BY in Oracle docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with an analytic:

```
select student, own_80_cnt,
       sum(own_80_cnt) over () total_80_cnt
  from (select student,
               sum(case when score = 80 then 1 else 0 end) as own_80_cnt
          from mytable
         group by student);
```

Comment: thanks! of the two solutions which should I choose in therms of performance? (the table I'm querying has 5 million records)

Comment: @BaseBallBatBoy test both then choose one :)

Answer (score 0):

add an inline subquery that separately gets the number of score equal to 80.

```
SELECT  student,
        SUM(CASE WHEN score = 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS own_80_cnt,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE score = 80) AS total_80_cnt
FROM    mytable 
GROUP BY student;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0ff4/10)

Comment: thanks! of the two solutions which should I choose in therms of performance? (the table I'm querying has 5 million records)